# CakePHP Pagination Routing Issues

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

Within CakePHP 2 I am using pagination which works great until I see the URL which is page:2, how can I make this ?page=2 ?

The next question is that I use this code for my controller which powers /domain.com/offers/top, /domain.com/offers/newest, /domain.com/offers/popular and then the categories like /domain.com/offers/tv-and-video. The thing is when it is paginated for /domain.com/offers/top instead of being /offers/top/page:2 it goes to /offers/bycategory/top/page:2.

```
 public function bycategory($slug = null)
{

    $userId = $this->Session->read("UserAuth.User.id");
    if ($slug == 'top') {
        //Get the top rated offers
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 15,
            'order' => array(
                'Offer.vote' => 'desc'
            )
        );
    } elseif ($slug == 'newest') {
        //Get the latest offers
        $this->paginate = array(

            'limit' => 15,
            'order' => array(
                'Offer.created' => 'desc'
            )
        );
    } elseif ($slug == 'popular') {
        //Get the most talked about offers
    } else {

        //This is the categories, so just get the category slug.
        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Category.slug =' => $slug),
            'limit' => 15,
            'order' => array(
                'Offer.created' => 'desc'
            )
        );


    }


    $offers = $this->paginate('Offer');

    // pass the value to our view.ctp
    $this->set('offers', $offers);
    $this->set('userId', $userId);

    $this->render('/Offers/index');


}
```

This is my custom route:

```
Router::connect(
'/offers/:catslug',
array('controller' => 'offers', 'action' => 'bycategory'),
array(

    'pass' => array('catslug')

));
```

Comment: Do not use cakephp pagination for achieving these goals.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make this ?page=2 ?

By setting the `paramType` option in paginator component options as mentioned in [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters).

You second issue looks like reverse routing issue. Have you setup any custom routes?

Comment: I have just added my custom route.

Comment: Your will have to use `PaginatorHelper:options()` to set the `catslug` route param for urls it generate or use the `persist` option in your `Route::connect()` statement so that `catslug` persists in url when reverse routing.